# What does "OC" mean?

Tags: resistance

My Bluegiga WT-32 manual ("Stereo CODEC ADC characteristics" table) says:

Allowed Load --> Resistive, min.:16(8)Ω , max.: **OC**

What does **OC** mean in this case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From context, I believe that means "open circuit" or infinite ohms.